# How to Use NgFor inside select option

Tags: angular

This is my typescript file and *ngFor is not working inside select option

I have tried this as pic below

```
<select type ="text" name="AccountNo" [(ngModel)]="val.AccountNo" class="form-control" > Select Account Number
                    <option>---Select---</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let sdata of savingData">
                        {{savingData.AccNum}}
                    </option>
                </select>
```

Comment: what do you see when you log savingData?

Comment: it should be `sdata.AccNum` not `savingData.AccNum`

Comment: @Input() public savingData:any=[];

Comment: i have array in savin gdata

Answer (score 2):

```
Your HTML -

<select [(ngModel)]="val.AccountNo" class="form-control" > Select Account Number
    <option>---Select---</option>
    <option *ngFor="let sdata of savingData" [value]="sdata.AccountNo">
        {{sdata.AccNum}}
    </option>
</select>
```

TS File -
You need to Declare Model -

```
val:any = {
    AccountNo : string = "";
};
```

You will get the value in model. Let me know if my answer help you in any kind.

Comment: i m not getting anything in {{sdata.AccNum}}

Comment: what was the `savingData` look like?

Comment: 0: {GroupNo: 3, GrpNum: 140, AccNum: "1010300001", AccountNo: 1, AccName: "RUBINA CHAUHAN",…}

Comment: @SarojJoshi strange. Can you provide stackblitz to identify the issue ?

Comment: @krunalShah Actually i m new to angular so i have no idea about stckblotz

Comment: <app-saving-item
        [savingData]="savingData" 
    ></app-saving-item>